# How to controls the views in a fragment from another fragment with an interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, communication

I'm building a meme generator app.  It has `2 fragments`.

The 1st fragment has `2 TextViews` and `an ImageView` below.
The 2nd fragment has `2 EditTexts` and `2 Buttons`.

The ImageView in the first fragment, which is clickable, has a placeholder image.

> 1- I want to change the visibility of the mentioned views in the 2nd fragment to `gone` if a different image is not selected
>
> 2- I want to do this by checking for the name of the drawable file.

I am told that I should use an interface for this.

> How do I use an interface to do orders?

Here is an example of an interface I've used in the same app.  I'd like to know what to do differently.

```
public class BottomControlsFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText topEditText, bottomEditText;
    Button btnCreate, btnReset;

    BottomControlsListener activityCommander;

    public interface BottomControlsListener{ void createMeme(String top, String bottom);}

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try{activityCommander = (BottomControlsListener) context;}

        catch (ClassCastException e){throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());}
    }
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomControlsFragment.BottomControlsListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void createMeme(String top, String bottom) {
        TopImageFragment topImageFragment = (TopImageFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
        topImageFragment.setMemeText(top, bottom);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TopImageFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    public void setMemeText(String top, String bottom){
        topTextView.setText(top);
        bottomTextView.setText(bottom);
    }

    ...
```

}

Comment: Are these fragments visible at the same time?? or you replace the second one with the first one?

Comment: They're visible at the same time.  One is the ImageView holder and the other is just EditTexts and Buttons that add captions to the Image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate between fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346704/how-to-communicate-between-fragments)

Answer (score 1):

You should use LocalBroadCast or viewModel, don't interface callback communication, it causes problems when fragment manager wants to start fragment independently

1. make a broadcast receiver to change visibility in 2st frag
2. register the broadcast receiver in onResume by `LocalBroadcastManager` instance, and unregister in `onPause`
3. check for difference image in 1st fragment when `notChanged` send intent with registered action in 2nd frag `onResume`, by `LocalBroadcastManager` instance. For more information, checkout samples on google

Update: Also if you want use interfaces, [Here is a complete tutorial](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud855/lessons/79936377-aa69-45ae-a386-d865dcb36518/concepts/5759d392-f965-4270-b6f7-3d92f4f7fa47)

Comment: @OnurOzbek I have added description to anwer

Comment: I was asking for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Google document says:

> The recommended way to communicate between fragments is to create a shared ViewModel object. Both fragments can access the ViewModel through their containing Activity. The Fragments can update data within the ViewModel, and if the data is exposed using LiveData, the new state will be pushed to the other fragment as long as it is observing the LiveData from the ViewModel. To see how to implement this kind of communication, read the 'Share data between Fragments' section in the ViewModel guide.

I recommend you to do it as well. Its how it gets done.

First, you need to create your viewModel:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

public void select(Item item) {
    selected.setValue(item);
}

public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
    return selected;
}
}
```

After that, you can use it in both of your fragments:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}


public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, { item ->
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

It's effortless to use. Let me know if you had any problem.

Comment: The issue is not "communicating between 2 fragments" in a vacuum.  How do I control the views in another fragment?  The examples that I'm watching on YouTube through are all about sending a text from one fragment to another.  I want to know the strategy behind controlling views in other fragments.